# how do you register a protocol for your iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So that clicking an url like this app://file1.html on the iphone will open your app?

Comment: That is not a protocol. A protocol defines the way data is shared across a network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a URL Types to your Info.plist [More Info](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html)

Comment: how do I tell if the url i want to register is taken or not?

Comment: Uniqueness is not up to you and it's not really a url. It's only the prefix. So choose something that is as unique as you think of. don't choose app:// or clock:// as some other app might also have the same one.